# What's the fastest way to get an image from an electron native module?

Tags: c++, node.js, module, electron, native

I need to run a high speed render in C++ *from Electron* - webgl is not adequate not enough features or horse power. Customer has specified that.

I will have a native C++ module doing a headless render.

I have an Electron renderer script called every 1/60th of a second to get the image from the native app and draw it to an html canvas.

Code follows.

```
const imageArray = getCurrentFrame(width, height); // This is the native wrapper
const clampedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageArray);
const imageData = new ImageData(clampedArray, width, height);
createImageBitmap(imageData).then(image => {
    gl.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

It works but slowly.

There is *a lot* of js overhead converting an array of unsigned bytes into an array of unsigned bytes. Absolutely no data manipulation is taking place - just lots of copying.The clamped array is clamping unsigned byte to unsigned byte - it's a slow non-operation.

I see several approaches to getting this done. Ideally a shared buffer for imageData which the native app can extract the image to directly. Possibly extending NAPI to handle ImageBitmap objects.

When done there will be some form of multiple buffering to prevent scan lines and flash - I'm not focused on that yet.

Comment: Why don't you return a clamped array from the wrapper in the first place?

Comment: Can't you just return `ImageData` directly? Your native function should have everything it needs - not quite sure if this comes with problems with NAPI.